# partly upload your input from a file

Tags: r, file, upload, shiny

I have a question about shiny. Can I partly take my input from a file.
For example I have 10 variables, 6 of them I introduce from keyboard and the rest of them, 4 I want to upload from a file. Is something like this possible with shiny?
My server.R looks something like this:

```
results<-simSIR(nsimulations=input$nsimulations, 
                    ncows=input$ncows, 
                    nvaccinated=input$nvaccinated, 
                    ninfectedinit=input$ninfectedinit, 
                    initvaccination=input$initvaccination, 
                    p=input$p,
                    freqvacc=input$freqvacc,
                    noutbreaks=input$noutbreaks,
                    lambdaiv=input$lambdaiv,  
                    lambdain=input$lambdain,  
                    muiv=input$muiv,
                    muin=input$muin,
                    an=input$an, 
                    bn=input$bn, 
                    av=input$av, 
                    bv=input$bv,
                    cost_vaccination=input$cost_vaccination,
                    daily_milk=input$daily_milk,
                    price_liter=input$price_liter,
                    grafic=F, 
                    parameters=T, 
                    writeitdown=F
    )

  })
```

And as you see I take from input all, and I wanted to take some parameters like: lambaiv,lambain,muiv,muin,an,bn,bv,av from a text file.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So far I have everything introduced by user, but I have set some default values (so I won't type always more than 10 values). I wanted to know if I can do this partly, because for me it doesn't make sense to take all the values from file

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you have tried so far or what exactly you want to accomplish but [this tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/) shows how to work with data files.

The key in that tutorial seems to be:

```
counties <- readRDS("census-app/data/counties.rds")
```

The is also an example using the `reactiveFileReader` at [this link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html).

```
fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'data.csv', read.csv)
```

Comment: Thank you for the link! I edited the post to be more specific!

Comment: I think with reactiveFileReader or readRDS you would have to take all data from the file, not how I want [some variables]. I put part of my server.R and explained a bit more clearly my problem.